# Trim hair/fur outside of clothes

Tags: particles, hair

I created a basic shirt for my character but can't manage to cut the hairs that go through it. What would be the shortest way to trim the "outer" fur? I know how to do it via simulating collisions and the *Force Field* applied to the shirt, but it is extra slow and really too much for a still render.
[image: How to make the shirt "impenetrable" for the fur?]

Comment: Have you tried hiding the shirt temporarily or using x-ray mode?

Comment: @RobertGützkow I haven't, but how will it affect the fur?

Comment: It doesn't affect the fur itself, but it makes editing with the cut or length tool easier. You may also want to limit the hair emitting to a vertex group that excludes the area under the vest. Both approaches assume that your character never takes the vest off.

Comment: @RobertGützkow Thanks, I'd know if there is another way to manage it. Blender has the Cut particles to the shape option that shows particles inside a mesh but i haven't found any "filter" or "wall" that simply does not show particles passing through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution so far is to apply the **mask texture to the hair material**. This can to not work smoothly with animations, but ok for still renders

[Here is the video titorial on how to manage it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5wvVCkSndig&list=PLcnnmeBCvTmJoOwPNNwUSSJbaSSy5QSmB&index=2&t=2s)

Hope that things will become better with the upcoming hair node system